# Enabling unfurl_links option via hubot-slack

Tags: node.js, hubot, slack-api

How do I enable the unfurl_links option when using hubot for slack adapter? I need to force unfurl_links as my http response is mostly text and contains url for images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a [hubot-slack issue (Add link unfurling option)](https://github.com/slackhq/hubot-slack/pull/96)

> We've just released a new version of hubot-slack that connects through a different API. URLs in messages posted through that API are always unfurled.